# Компьютеры в одной рабочей группе перестают видеть друг друга при смене IP-адреса сети

Tags: windows, сеть, ip, коммутатор, smb

Есть сеть примерно из 40 компьютеров под управлением различных ОС: Windows XP, Windows 7, Windows 10. Сеть без доменов. Имя рабочей группы WORKGROUP. Адрес сети 192.168.1.Х. Основной шлюз 192.168.1.1. Меняю адрес сети на 192.168.100.Х и основной шлюз на 192.168.100.1. При этом некоторые компьютеры вообще пропадают из сетевого окружения, а некоторые остаются видны, но у них пропадает доступ к общим ресурсам. В основном такая ерунда с компьютерами под управлением WINDOWS XP и WINDOWS 7. "Десятки" видят другие компьютеры и сами видны в сетевом окружении.
P.S. Сеть объединена с помощью 5 коммутаторов.

Comment: WINS-сервер есть? если нет - мастер-браузер статический, или как получится? вообще NetBIOS хоть как-то настроен?

Comment: PS. А вообще - за каким требуется менять сеть? да ещё и регулярно?

Comment: *В основном такая ерунда с компьютерами под управлением WINDOWS XP и WINDOWS 7. "Десятки" видят другие компьютеры и сами видны в сетевом окружении.* Включена ли на десятке поддержка 40- и 56-битного шифрования? Включена ли поддержка SMB версии 1.0? Нет ли в сети десяток со сборкой 1703?